# Django | Paginator | Conseguir número total de páginas y número actual de página

Tags: django

Cómo conseguir con paginator en la view o en el template, el **número actual de página** de la página y el **número total de páginas**.

```
def pregunta_list(request, categoria_id):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(categoria=categoria_id).order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
    #paginas totales:
    paginatorTotal = count(Paginator(preguntas))
    #número de página actual:
    paginaActual = ¿¿Paginator...??
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'pregunta/pregunta.html', {'preguntas': preguntas})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber cual es el **numero de la pagina actual**, es simple:

```
request.GET.get('page')
```

Si quieres acceder a la **pagina actual**, como tal, es así:

```
>>> page_x = paginator.page(request.GET.get('page'))
>>> page_x.object_list
[...]
```

Para saber el numero total de paginas:

```
>>> paginator.num_pages
...
```

Y por ultimo si quieres saber el total de objetos del paginador:

```
>>> paginator.count
...
```

Todo esto **y mas**, se explica en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/#pagination), con mas detalle.

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio Cesar. Tus respuestas siempre tan completas.